# Eclipse Paho Automatic Reconnect configure

Tags: mqtt, paho

As provided in documentation of java client's `automaticReconnect` feature:

> Once the client has been disconnected, the client will attempt to
>   connect with an increasing time interval. Starting at 1 second,
>   doubling on each failed attempt up to 2 minutes.

But It raises some questions over client behavior:

1. After 2 minutes limit, Will client keep trying to connect indefinitely? 
   As I am not able to find any other parameter to control this iteration.
2. Is there any way available to configure this interval ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [MqttAsyncClient.java](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java/blob/master/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3/src/main/java/org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/MqttAsyncClient.java) source code (I have removed few lines below):

```
/**
 * Attempts to reconnect the client to the server.
 * If successful it will make sure that there are no further
 * reconnects scheduled. However if the connect fails, the delay will double
 * up to 128 seconds and will re-schedule the reconnect for after the delay.
 * 
 * Any thrown exceptions are logged but not acted upon as it is assumed that 
 * they are being thrown due to the server being offline and so reconnect
 * attempts will continue.
 */
private void attemptReconnect(){
    final String methodName = "attemptReconnect";   
    //@Trace 500=Attempting to reconnect client: {0}
    log.fine(CLASS_NAME, methodName, "500", new Object[]{this.clientId});

    connect(this.connOpts, this.userContext,new IMqttActionListener() {

        public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
            //@Trace 501=Automatic Reconnect Successful: {0}
            log.fine(CLASS_NAME, methodName, "501", new Object[]{asyncActionToken.getClient().getClientId()});
            comms.setRestingState(false);
            stopReconnectCycle();
        }

        public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
            //@Trace 502=Automatic Reconnect failed, rescheduling: {0}
            log.fine(CLASS_NAME, methodName, "502", new Object[]{asyncActionToken.getClient().getClientId()});
            if(reconnectDelay < 128000){
                reconnectDelay = reconnectDelay * 2;
            }
            rescheduleReconnectCycle(reconnectDelay);
        }
    });
}
```

So the reconnect delay will be: `1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 128, 128, 128, ...`

Comment: So it will try to reconnect indefinitely, and is there any configuration to stop this. say after 10 retrial stop connecting.

Comment: Sure: modify the above java file and compile your custom version of Paho. Or disable automatic reconnect and handle it in your code. If I have answered your question, do not forget to mark it as accepted answer.